# Why Asp.Net core app embedded with an iframe can't be seen only when working on a mobile devices?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, iframe, mobile

I have embedded  a Dot net Core app in an Angular using an iframe.
When I work on Windows and using a Chrome (or IE) browser everything works well , I see an iframe's contents.But when I use an Android mobile device the chrome browser doesn't show any content inside an iframe and after a while I get that it took too long to respond.

```css
.responsive-iframe {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
 }
```

```html
<!-- <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe id="vic" [src]="path" allowfullscreen scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div> -->


<div class="container">
        <iframe class="responsive-iframe" src="https://eforms-pp.hargal.co.il:4443/PdfComponent/1/1/1"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I doubt that this is not related to `asp.net core` at all. First try showing any URL in your iframe to see if it works. Second if that's not relevant due to some client-side logic that need a specific page to be loaded, check if there is any wrong logic on the client-side (only `javascript` and Angular are involved). Finally ensure that your asp.net core page loads quickly enough (measure its performance, even try mocking any loading & computing logic to make it fast for testing).

Comment: Yes, I linked other external url to iframe's src and it worked both on a mobile and on windows. I believe , that the issue is with our asp.net page loading time,that makes an impact on mobile..but I am not sure..